# jquery difference between bind('resize') vs .resize()

Tags: jquery

1. What is the difference between `$(window).bind('resize')` and `$(window).resize()`?
2. I saw somewhere `bind` nested over `resize`. What impact does it have? See code below.
3. I know `.resize()` works on elements as well as window. Does `bind` work in similar way too...
   like `$('#el').bind('resize', function (event) { // stuff });`?

**JS:**

```
$(window).bind('resize', function (event) {
    $(window).resize(function () {
         // do something here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) page `.resize()`:

> This method is a shortcut for .on('resize', handler).

and `.on()` is:

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For
>   help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), 
>   .delegate(), and .live().

So based on jQuery api description, I think there is no difference it's just a shortcut similar to `$.click()` and others